# How write $abc as string value in shell scripting

Tags: shell, ubuntu, nginx

well i am creating a script file to save the following content

```
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
```

all other content are written correctly but $remote_addr is not added to the file i mean i am not sending the value of $remote_addr i want actual content in the file with $remote_addr 
i tried by encapsulating with '' but no success.

What i have done is

```
echo "server {
  listen                *:80;
  server_name           $SERVER_NAME;

  access_log            /var/log/nginx/app.dev.access.log;
error_log             /var/log/nginx/app.dev.error.log;
  location / {
    proxy_pass $PROXY_PASS;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade '$http_upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For '$remote_addr';
  }
}
"
```

Comment: Please show your work so we can help you find the errors.

Comment: echo "server { listen *:80;

server_name $SERVER_NAME;

access_log /var/log/nginx/app.dev.access.log;

error_log /var/log/nginx/app.dev.error.log;

location / {

proxy_pass $PROXY_PASS;

proxy_http_version 1.1;

proxy_set_header Upgrade '$http_upgrade';

proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';

proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For '$remote_addr';
}

} "

Comment: Inside double quotes, single quotes lose their special meaning. You'll have to backslash-escape the variables you do not want expanded. See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Quoting

Comment: Thanks it worked when i echo  but when i try to save content to a file in the server it just saves with the $ content....

Answer (score 1):

To prevent the shell from interpreting the dollar sign, backslash it:

```
echo \$remote_addr
```

or, use single quotes

```
echo '$remote_addr'
```